# what kind of DeepSecurityManager's Date on SQL database

Tags: deepsecurity

I am using the 30days trial version of Deep Security Manager.
I'm trying to find where I can check the DSM's logs and DSA's logs.
I heard that all logs are stored in SQL. but I can't find it.

AWS EC2 InstanceA(Installed DSM and SQL Server Express 2017)
I created sample database for DSM by commandline, and login as created user using SSMS.

AWS EC2 InstanceB(Installed DSA)

I checked InstanceB is online as computer  on the DSM.

I created some security rules.

what I want to check is, 
I installed Agent on InstanceB, and DSM installed on InstanceA.
I can check DeepSecurityManagement Console that DSM's Relay is enable or not.
now, I'd like to understand what's date I've got on SQL.
I can login SQL and I found database which I created for DSM.
But I don't know what kind of date I've got on SQL, so 
I don't know which date I should check. I also can't find any documents.

If someone know what kind of date is store on SQL. 
Please tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are no details of the DSM data schema in SQL that is public.  Deep Security Manager logs are stored in a file called server0.log, found in the root of the directory where DSM is  installed.

I am a Trend Micro employee.

-Nick